# If element size is smaller than X, then

Tags: jquery, css, height

I would like to change attributes of element if the height is less than 700px. So I tried this code:

```
if ($('.content').height() < 700) {
    $( "#footer" ).css( "position", "absolute" ); 
};
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Where am I making mistake?
Thank you.

Comment: Does the condition work? Add a console.log() to see if it does

Comment: what is the current height of the .content element? Does it fullfill the condition? This code seems to work. Please take a look at this fiddle and run console: http://jsfiddle.net/u5xasLrm/1/

Comment: are you checking this on domcontentloaded? on window.resize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it :)

outerHeight - http://api.jquery.com/outerheight/

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
        var contentHeight = $('.content').outerHeight();    
        if ( contentHeight < 700) {    
            $( "#footer" ).css( "position", "absolute" );    
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using: `.style.height`

Inner height: `document.getElementById("id").clientHeight`

Outer height: `document.getElementById("id").offsetHeight`

Comment: Firstly, the OP has specified only jQuery in the tags on the question. Secondly, these are all irrelevant to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. You just need to check if the condition is true or not. you can check it either using console.log("it works") or alert("it is true").

I believe you want to change the attribute after some event.

```
$("btn").on("click", function(){

   //to check if event is fired or not
   alert("clicked");
   //if you want to check your condition in console
   console.log($('.content').height() < 700)

  if ($('.content').height() < 700) {
     $( "#footer" ).css( "position", "absolute" );
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

As I tried your example provided above, its working fine.

I need more details on what exactly you want to achieve.

As I understood you want to add and remove position absolute based on the content height on page load and page resize if I am not wrong.
If this is the case then try the below code.

```
function handleFooter () {
  if ($('.content').height() < 250) {
    $( "#footer" ).css( "position", "absolute" );
  } else {
    $( "#footer" ).css( "position", "static" );
  }
}

handleFooter();

$(window).resize(function() {
  handleFooter();
});
```

If this is not solving your problem then give more info or extra code snippets so that I can help you better